# Same link in menu and in footer are in different languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

My ASP.NET MVC 4 website URLs looks like this "/language/controller/action".

HTML code of link in menu and in footer are the same.

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("WebsiteDevelopment", "Service", new { area = "" })">Website development</a></li>
```

When site is opened in "en-GB" culture link in menu pinting to

```
/en-GB/Service/WebsiteDevelopment
```

But link in footer is

```
/hy-AM/Service/WebsiteDevelopment
```

How it is possible? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last menu was changing entire language to Armenian. Aa a route value it takes place after that function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify "language" in Url.Action, so it probably takes the default language.
ASP.NET links are absolute ones, so without specifying the language, it's

```
/default-language/controller/action
```

If you want the language to be taken from the current URL, you need to write your own Url.Action function, or extend it.

Comment: I do not set default language. Same code is in header and footer. Header works fine, footer not.